# CKEditor not displaying correctly after update to Drupal v8.3.5

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I've just updated a Drupal 8 site to v8.3.5 I've also updated the security patches that were available.  I've cleared the cache and checked for issues.  The main issue is that CKEditor isn't displaying correctly.  Weirdly it is working on my local copy of the site, I've committed the changes and pushed them to the repo.  I've pulled the updates on to another server and that's where its showing this issue.  I've tried changing file permissions etc but so far no success.

Any suggestions on how to sort this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The skins folder which should be in `core/assets/vendor/ckeditor` was missing.  It was missing because it was in the `.gitignore` file.  Added this folder and its contents back in and its now working correctly.